# Unreferenced external symbol during DLL function call

Tags: c++, dll, import, export

I'm having problems in implementing a class in a DLL in the same way it is explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/howto_export_cpp_classes.aspx#CppMatureApproach)
. I have my interface with all the methods declared as virtual, I have my class that implements the interface and I have the method that should create the object of the class. The problem is here, when I try to use it I get a "unreferenced external symbol" error. Why?

```
class IXYZ
{
    virtual void XXX() = 0;
};

class XYZ : public IXYZ
{
    void XXX();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IXYZ* __stdcall GetIXYZ();
#endif
```

and I use it inside my win32 program with:

```
IXYZ *myvar = GetIXYZ();
```

In my exe program I've included the .h file of the dll

Comment: Did you change declspec to dllimport for the application?

Comment: Did you link the lib file for the DLL when building the app?

Comment: @PiorLegnica yes i'm using the standard visual studio macro for exporting things

Comment: You've checked with Dependency Walker that the function is exported?

Comment: @David no you are true but it's strange, if I try to link the library it says that it cannot find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've correctly defined the function in the DLL, and it is exported properly, then the only plausible explanation is that there is something wrong with your use of the .lib file in the application that uses the DLL.

Comment: ok, if I link the lib file it works but I don't know why for one of my lib files it says that it cannot find it. Mistery

Comment: you can inspect .lib files with dumpbin

Comment: I fixed the problem, I set the lib directory to be the debug directory where the .lib files are created but when I compile the files are deleted and recreated so it gives that error. The problem now is: which directory should I use to have always the latest lib files?

Comment: @Stefano I'm not sure I can help you much with that one. I never use Visual Studio so I don't know what the natural workflow is for VS.